# I have the critic badge but I did not downvote?

Tags: support, badges, down-votes

Today I have found - in the *Votes Cast* statistics on stack overflow - that my votes was decreased by 10. At the begining, I thought I was mistaken. Then, I realised that the statistics says that I have casted 0 down votes. That can't be true if I have the Critic badge.. right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be correct -- if you cast a downvote, wait a bit, then undo it.

Badges are generally never rescinded, so you would have critic with no downvotes in that case.

(File under: yet another in the litany of reasons that vote undo windows are hugely problematic..)

Comment: Alternatively, this could be filed under "reasons that badges should be revoked following rep recalculations".

Comment: I've never downvoted and still there is the badge.

Comment: @SomeGuy the database disagrees with your statement...

Comment: Database may disagree, but I am 100% absolutely sure. I got badge notice today, but I've been inactive for about a week.